# How to redirect jar output from ubuntu command prompt to text file

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

I created jar file and I run it using command as follows:

```
$ java -jar niidle.jar arguments...
```

it is showing correct output.
But I cant see the whole output.
I want to see the whole output.
so how to redirect this whole thing to text file, when I run following command:

```
$ java -jar niidle.jar arguments...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
jar -jar niidle.jar arguments > output
```

Comment: I would suggest to do :  jar -jar niidle.jar arguments 2>&1 > output to capture the stdout and stderr

Answer (score 3):

This should do !!

java -jar class.jar  2>> log.txt

Answer (score 1):

To save error logs in a file and normal console logs in another file:

```
java -jar niidle.jar arguments 2> errorOutput.log > output.log
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to save the output for future reference, you can read the full output this way:

```
java -jar niidle.jar arguments | less
```

Obviously, we are supposing that there is no user interaction. Otherwise you can do something like the following example to save the output and review it later.

```
java -jar niidle.jar arguments | tee output
... some user interaction ...
less output
```