# MS-DOS output should be print on *txt file

Tags: perl

**Edited:**
I am doing the validation for XHTML Files. Hence I using the below code to parse the xhtml file *(particularly from this jar file not parsing modules)*:

The output printed on the MS-Dos Prompt is like:

```
"file:009_chapter004_9783990309544.xhtml":830.1-830.5: info warning: A table row was 1 columns wide, which is less than the column count established by the first row (2).
"file:009_chapter004_9783990309544.xhtml":833.1-833.5: info warning: A table row was 1 columns wide, which is less than the column count established by the first row (2).
"file:009_chapter004_9783990309544.xhtml":836.1-836.5: info warning: A table row was 1 columns wide, which is less than the column count established by the first row (2).
"file:009_chapter004_9783990309544.xhtml":839.1-839.5: info warning: A table row was 1 columns wide, which is less than the column count established by the first row (2).
"file:009_chapter004_9783990309544.xhtml":842.1-842.5: info warning: A table row was 1 columns wide, which is less than the column count established by the first row (2).
"file:009_chapter004_9783990309544.xhtml":845.1-845.5: info warning: A table row was 1 columns wide, which is less than the column count established by the first row (2).
"file:009_chapter004_9783990309544.xhtml":826.1-826.33: error: Table column 2 established by element ΓÇ£tdΓÇ¥ has no cells beginning in it.
```

In perl script how to convert `MS-Dos output` into the `*.txt` file from following command:

```
#Try - 1 
system("java -Xss512k -jar \"c:/vnu.jar_18.11.5/dist/vnu.jar\" 009_chapter004_8883990309533.xhtml >Output.txt");

#Try - 2 
my $output = system("java -Xss512k -jar \"c:/vnu.jar_18.11.5/dist/vnu.jar\" 009_chapter004_8883990309533.xhtml");

#Try - 3 
perl -w htmlvalidation.pl  >Output.txt;
```

However not success on the above code. Could someone help me on this one.

Comment: I'm afraid that in order for us to be any help to you, you're going to have to be a lot clearer about what the problem is. What are you trying to achieve here and what unexpected behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: @DaveCross: Question updated.

Comment: What is `htmlvalidation.pl`?

Comment: To capture output of an external command, see e.g. [IPC::Run3](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run3) and [Capture::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny)

Comment: @DaveCross: `Try -1` & `Try - 2` in the `htmlvalidation.pl`

Comment: @HåkonHægland: Yes we will check. thanks

Comment: @HåkonHægland: I tried the IPC::Run3 and Capture::Tiny but I couldn't run java parameters with input and output... It shows error. Could you please provide few sample.

Answer (score 1):

[I got the answer from - N Deepak Prasath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18844390/4251338)

I couldn't understand the below scenario but fortunately I got answer:

We need to add the  `2>> output.txt` instead of using `>output.txt`.

> Tried code:

`system("java -Xss512k -jar vnu.jar 009_chapter004_8883990309533.xhtml >Output.txt");`

> Now working Code:

`system("java -Xss512k -jar vnu.jar 009_chapter004_8883990309533.xhtml 2>>Output.txt");`

I am trying/searching the above from the last two days now I got the answer and updating here since someone get benefits from the above.